# Carousel adding query string parameter for slide as "carousel=0" or "carousel=1"

Tags: sxa

I have added SXA (v1.6) OOTB box carousel component and added some slides. After publishing the page, it is adding slide number as query string parameters"/Home?carousel=0" on the browser's URL.

and the numbers are changing whenever the slide changes.

Please provide me the pointers to resolve this issue.

In previous version of the SXA (1.5 and below), this is not happening.

Comment: It's not a bug - it's a feature. Where do you see an issue here?

Comment: In Sitecore 8.2 with sxa, its not appending the query string parameter, but in SC9-SXA its happening. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: What version of the platform and SXA are you using?

Comment: Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 SXA 1.6 rev 180103

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the latest SXA v1.6 has this as a new "feature" to support the browser's history and direct linking to the carousel slides. It is tightly associated with the "bullet navs". To remove this, you have 2 options:

Option A. Remove the "bullet navs".  Edit the carousel component and select `None` for the `Navigation Type`.  Save and publish the page.

Option B. Update the theme's carousel JS file.  Use [Creative Exchange Live](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/creative_exchange/modify_site_design_with_creative_exchange_live) and export the page that has the carousel.  Edit the carousel component JS which is located at:

-\media\Themes\\\scripts\component-carousel.js

Comment the line (line 344):

> updateQueryParam(componentRoot.attr('id') || "carousel", index);

Save it and publish the theme.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will verify and let you know.

Comment: I wouldn't suggestion second option. Please remember that all SXA items which you will modify will be overridden while upgrading SXA to the latest version. You will lose all your modifications.

Comment: David, I wouldn't recommend changing the original either but you can make a copy of the theme and update that instead.